# Braintree - Securing client - server communication

Tags: braintree

While integrating BrainTree (client and server) for a new solution, I have been wondering whether it's "safe" to maintain a non secure connection between my BT client (mobile app) and my BT server (web service). I.e. a web service without SSL in my case.

Thinking about it, even if someone discovers my non secure BT Server (web service) and sends remote calls, it shouldn't be too bad since BT (a) needs a payment nonce to generate a transaction, and (b) unless auto-settlement is enabled in BT, transactions won't be sent out for settlement without you manually doing so.

Am I wrong? Do you see any reasons for SSL and securing connection?

Many thanks,
Polis

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a secure connection, HOWEVER I recommend that you do have SSL enabled. When users see a credit card form without a secure connection, they may not trust your site. They don't know (and shouldn't even care about) the security details. They'll just see that SSL is not enabled and assume their data is not secure.

Comment: They won't see that though as it's a mobile app integration.